# I want to get method from mongodb with using limit and i am sending a a query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Actually i am confused with the limit method of mongodb. My code should send only data of two hotels and i am doing query req from the backend .

```
export const getHotels = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const hotels = await Hotel.find(req.query).limit(req.query.limit)
        res.status(200)
        res.json(hotels)
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
}
```

The above is the code i had written for the query req.
And

```
localhost:8800/api/hotels?featured=true&limit=2
```

Its my backend url which must send me the data of only 2 hotels

```
router.get('/countByType',countByType);
```

And the above is the router get method i am using

Comment: Your post is well structured, however what is the issue? What are you instead getting in `console.log(hotels)`?

Comment: Yeah, looks fine to me - what is the actual problem? Is it returning more than 2? I don't have a mongoose setup to test with, but if that's the issue try checking that the value really is 2 and then try casting the string "2" to an actual number

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use the **limit** route query param in the Mongo query **find** method?

If No, try to change the code to:

```js
export const getHotels = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const filter = {
            featured: req.query.featured
        };
        const limit = +req.query.limit;
        const hotels = await Hotel.find(filter).limit(limit);
        res.status(200)
        res.json(hotels)
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
}
```

[[See that you should convert limit to int]]

Moreover, How the field **featured** is saved in your Mongo collection?
As a boolean or string "true"?
If as a boolean, you should do a type conversion. For example:

```js
export const getHotels = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const filter = {
            featured: req.query.featured === "true"
        };
        const limit = +req.query.limit;
        const hotels = await Hotel.find(filter).limit(limit);
        res.status(200)
        res.json(hotels)
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
}
```

I'm confused about the following line of code:

```js
router.get('/countByType',countByType);
```

Did you mean to write: **router.get('/api/hotels', getHotels);** ?